# PHP regex not working, despite successfully matching in regex101

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm having the weirdest issue.  I've tried referencing other similar answers here, but none seem to fix my issue.

I have the following regex in PHP

`/if\s+(?:(.*?)\s*==\s*(?:UrlStatus|DeadURL)|in_array\s*\((?:UrlStatus|DeadURL),\s*(.*?)\s*\))\s*then\s+local\s+arch_text\s+=\s+cfg.messages\['archived'\];(?:(?:\n|.)*?if\s+(?:(.*?)\s*==\s*(?:UrlStatus|DeadURL)|in_array\s*\((?:UrlStatus|DeadURL),\s*(.*?)\s*\))\s*then\s+Archived = sepc \.\.)?/im`

It's a messy regex I know, it's supposed to parse code from a module of various versions from different location.  It works perfectly in regex101, but preg_match returns false, indicating an error occured.  The regex you see is pulled straight from a var_dump.  Also pulled from the var_dump is the string being tested.  I have included the excerpt that is supposed to match it below.

````
    if is_set(ArchiveURL) then
        if not is_set(ArchiveDate) then
            ArchiveDate = seterror('archive_missing_date');
        end
        if "no" == DeadURL then
            local arch_text = cfg.messages['archived'];
            if sepc ~= "." then arch_text = arch_text:lower() end
            Archived = sepc .. " " .. substitute( ```

In the full block of text it takes 81,095 steps to match.  
Could it have something to do with that?
````

Comment: Have you looked at the output of [`preg_last_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-last-error.php)?

Comment: Have you heard about our lord and saviour, the regex `/x` readability flag?

Comment: @Nick it appears to return PREG_JIT_STACKLIMIT_ERROR.  Though I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: @Cyberpower678 there's a note about disabling `JIT` on the constants definition [page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.constants.php)

Comment: @Nick any chance this can be disabled with ini_set?  I have no access to php.ini on one of the prod servers I run the code on.

Comment: @Cyberpower678 looks like [it can](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php#ini.pcre.jit)

Comment: @Nick Stackoverflow is a beautiful place.  $old = ini_set( 'pcre.jit', false ); did the trick and now it's matching. :D

Comment: @Cyberpower678 good to hear! I'm glad I was able to help out.

Comment: @Cyberpower678 you should probably post your solution as an answer (explaining what the problem actually was) and accept it as it might be useful to other users.

Comment: @Nick I'm thinking you should.  You are the one that helped me. :-)

Comment: @Cyberpower678 not really - I just helped you help yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting a read from preg_last_error(), it returned 6, which maps to the constant PREG_JIT_STACKLIMIT_ERROR.

PHP 7 uses a JIT compiler for preg_match with a small stack size limit.  Disabling it allows preg_match to do its job.

This can be done in the php.ini file, or on the fly in the script by using `ini_set( 'pcre.jit', false );`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! YOU'RE A LIFE SAVER!! ALL HAIL Cyberpower678!!!